# jQuery内部でnew Date()が「このオブジェクトではサポートされていない操作です」というエラーになる

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

jQueryの内部で`new Date()`が「このオブジェクトではサポートされていない操作です」というエラーを吐いています。
これを回避する方法が知りたいです。

再現条件が分からず、最小限の再現ソースを提示できないので、代わりに状況を説明させてください。
なお、再現を確認した環境はIE11とEdgeです。Chromeでは発生していません。

次の画像は、IE11の開発者ツール（F12）です。
見えているソースは、jQuery 1.11.3のものです。

[image: jquery]

次の画像は、上記のエラー発生時のコールスタックです。
上から8つ目の`request.js`は、私が書いたコードです。
jQueryの`ajax`メソッドを呼んでいます。

[image: コールスタック]

次の画像は、エラー発生時にデバッガが止まっている状況で、変数ウォッチからグローバル変数`Date`を確認したところです。
なぜか`undefined`になっています。
エラーの根本的な原因は分かりませんが、直接的な原因はこれのようです。

[image: ウォッチ Date]

次の画像は、上記と同様に`jQuery`変数が存在しているかどうか確認したところです。
`jQuery`は見つかりましたが、なぜか`$`が`undefined`です。

[image: ウォッチ jQuery]

次の画像は、上記のウォッチで確認しているときにIEがクラッシュしたところです。
ウォッチのリストに、`jQuery`をもう一度追加したところでクラッシュしました。
何度か試しましたところ、クラッシュのタイミングは若干前後するものの、`jQuery`を2回以上ウォッチに追加することで再現します。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

**追記**

上記の問題のコードでは必ず発生します。

コールスタックの上から6番目、「非同期呼び出し」の次の行にあるsendの部分でブレークポイントを貼って止めてみると‌​、その時点ではDateが存在します。  
また、Dateがundefinedだったのと同様に、StringやNumberなどもundefinedになっていました。

Comment: 再現条件がわからないとありますが、動いたり動かなかったりするのですか？問題のコードでは必ず発生し、[`$.ajax()` を呼び出すだけのコード](https://jsfiddle.net/bufb0q6o/)では問題なく動くのだとすれば、両者の違う部分が原因となっている可能性が高いですから、順番にコードを減らしていきながら原因箇所を絞り込むことができそうなのですが。 / どこかでDateが書き換えられている（[書き換える例](https://jsfiddle.net/j671tnjy/)）というのがわかりやすいですが、これならChromeでも動かないですしね。。

Comment: 問題のコードでは必ず発生します。もちろん、最悪はそのように地道に調べていくことになりますが、現在その時間が取れないため、何か情報を得て当たりをつけたいと考えていたところです。

Comment: なお、コールスタックの上から6番目、「非同期呼び出し」の次の行にある`send`の部分でブレークポイントを貼って止めてみると、その時点では`Date`が存在します。

Comment: また、`Date`が`undefined`だったのと同様に、`String`や`Number`なども`undefined`になっていました。

Comment: といった追加情報はぜひ質問の方に書いていただけませんか？/ IE9の頃に似たような話があるにはあるようですが（ https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8779 http://stackoverflow.com/q/9695099/2818869 ）、ここにも再現方法が載っていないので原因調査以前に再現が難しいですね・・・

Answer (score 1):

デバッグ中にブラウザが落ちてしまうというのは大変ですね。
例えば下記のように、`Date`(必要であれば`$`も)の変更を監視・拒否するように、プログラム冒頭のグローバル名前空間で仕込んでおくというのはどうでしょうか。

```
// Date の変更を拒否する
const orig_date = Date;
Object.defineProperty(
    this, "Date", {
        set: function(v){
            console.log("!NOT ALLOWED: set Date:", v);
            console.trace();
        },
        get: function(){ return orig_date; },
    }
);
```